# How can I make an HTML table auto width but larger than the screen?

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

I have a wide table – possibly *very* wide – and I *want* the table to be as wide as necessary to fit everything, i.e. as-if it the width was `auto` (and the screen was wider).

But, by default, tables seem to never exceed the size of their containers!

I've found an answer using JavaScript, but is there a pure CSS answer too? Or a better JavaScript solution?

[Here's a JSFiddle fiddle with an example table](http://jsfiddle.net/kenny_evitt/KmXSb/). Note that in this example the content *is* bigger than the 'screen', but the desired effect should cause the width of the cells to be large enough so that the text of each cell is all on a single line.

[Per GChabot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21640034/173497), I don't want the cells to be bigger than their contents. Per their subsequent comment, by "fit everything", I'm of course referring to the Goldilocks fit, i.e. just enough so that contents don't wrap, but no larger.

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle? Can you avoid setting the width of a container?

Comment: @LorDex – yeah, I'll make a JSFiddle. I don't think I can avoid setting the width of the container; the container is just the page `body`.

Comment: you must have some width set up for body, because by default there shouldn't be a problem: http://jsfiddle.net/jzwm5/

Comment: @LorDex – Add another word to each of those cells; I expect that the contents will wrap onto another line and that's not what I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the cells up so they do not wrap

```
td { white-space: nowrap; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you mean by "fit everything", you might want to define a min-width for your `td`s:

```
min-width:250px;
```

That way, each cell has a reasonable size to display some text, on one or more lines (or just one if you set them as `nowrap` as epascarello suggested). If you are displaying fixed-size element (such as images), the table should expand by default.

Comment: I don't want the cells to be bigger than their contents.

Comment: What do you mean by "fit everything"? Isn't epascarello's solution working for you?

Answer (score 1):

CSS overflow should fix your issue take a look at this post http://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/

Comment: I read the post and tried adding `overflow: auto;` to the table's `style`, but that doesn't work. Which `overflow` setting does what I'm asking?

Comment: overflow:auto; should work but you need to set it at container level

Comment: Setting `overflow: auto;` on the table container works! But the horizontal scroll-bar is on the container; I'd prefer it on the page/screen.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the quick-and-dirty JavaScript I'm using now:

```
$('#table-container').attr('style', 'width: 1000%');
$('#table-container').attr('style', 'width: ' + $('#tblMain').width() + 'px;');
```

`#table-container` refers to a `div` surrounding the table; the table has an `id` of `tblMain`.

I know this won't work if the table is 10 times wider than the current screen size, but a general solution should be pretty easy to implement.